# Is it possible to apply gradient to a tiled background image using CSS3 or like?

Tags: javascript, html, css

You might find this question to be a possible duplicate of the following:
[Does CSS3 support using both an image and a gradient for the background of a single ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005017/does-css3-support-using-both-an-image-and-a-gradient-for-the-background-of-a-sing)
But I further the question and want to know if I can apply the CSS3 Gradient to the complete page with the image tiled to repeat throughout the screen.
Hope I get an answer to this. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this thread..

[CSS3 Radial Gradients with RGBA()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464571/css3-radial-gradients-with-rgba)

And please do some homework before asking questions.